# node.js built in support for handling requests for same data

Tags: node.js

In my node.js server app I'm providing a service to my js client that performs some handling of remote api's.

It might very well be possible that two different clients request the same information. Say client 1 requests information, then before client 1's request is fully handled (remote api's didn't returns their response yet) client 2 is requesting the same data. What I'd want to is to wait for client 1 data to be ready and then write it to both client 1 and 2.

This seems to me like a very common issue and I was wondering if there was any library or built-in support in connect or express that supports this issue.

Comment: doesn't look like a common issue at all to me. actually very strange behavior i would say.

Answer (score 1):

You might not want to use HTTP for providing the data to the client. Reasons:

1. If the remote API is taking a lot of time to process you will risk the client request to timeout, or the browser to repeat the request.
2. You will have to share some state between requests which is not a good practice.

Have a look at [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) ([socket.io](http://socket.io/) would be a place to start). With them you can push data from the server to the client. In your scenario, clients will perform the request to the server, which will return [202](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) and when the remote API will respond, the server will push the data to the clients using websockets.